Ag-Charts 10.2 is Not Loading in Require.JS App
I have a require.js app and I am adding enterprise edition of Ag-Charts in it. I can successfully add 9.0 version of Ag-Charts but when I try to add 10.2 version, it's not loading somehow. Can someone please help? Following is my code snippet.
require.config({
    paths: {
        vue: "./MyModules/libs/vuejs/vue.min",
        vueloader: "./MyModules/libs/requirejs/requirejs-vue",
        Vuetify: "./MyModules/libs/vuetify/vuetify.min",
        agChartsComm : 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-charts-enterprise@9.0.0/dist/umd/ag-charts-enterprise', 
        CSSVuetify: "./MyModules/libs/vuetify/vuetify.min",
        CSSMaterialDesign: "./MyModules/styles/MaterialDesign/css/materialdesignicons.min",
        CSSWidget: "./WidgetInfo/styles/styles"
    
    }
    
});

function executeWidgetCode() {
    require([
        "vue", 
        "vueloader!WidgetInfo/components/app",
        "Vuetify",
        "agChartsComm",
        "css!CSSVuetify",
        "css!CSSMaterialDesign",
        "css!CSSWidget",
    ], function (Vue, myApp, Vuetify, agCharts) {
        console.log("AG Charts >> " + agCharts);

In here 9.0 version works fine and I get console output as "AG Charts >> [object, object]
I want to use linear gauge which comes with 10.2
But when I try with 10.2 like below,
agChartsComm : 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-charts-enterprise@10.2.0/dist/umd/ag-charts-enterprise', 

I get "AG Charts >> undefined"
I tried multiple things but it doesn't work at all. Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance.
I am expecting the 10.2 to be loaded in my require.js application

This suggests that there could be a problem with UMD module, i.e. a bug to report. Please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged.
